# JavaFX Native Installer OSX Working Directory

Tags: macos, installation, javafx-2, plist

On every other platform but Mac OSX, when I build and install a native package, the default working directory is "." to the JAR file.  Even on OSX, if I delve inside the .app folder and manually run the JAR, the working directory is correct.  However, if I run the application by simply clicking on the .app launcher, the working path ends up as "/Users/[username]
".  Does anyone know how to configure the JavaFX native installer (perhaps info.plist?) to prevent this from occurring?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  My logback.xml file has a file name configured - works great until I launch the .app.  Thanks for letting me know it's in ${user.home}

Answer (score 0):

I think the launcher native executable sets this path. It is not plist configurable. The reasoning seemed to be in anticipation of OS X sandboxed applications and the limited file system access that they involve. So, basically there was no real good choice but they didn't want to encourage counting on access to the application bundle or it's parent directory.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, they are asking how can they prevent the problem.